# Copy formulas on one sheet dynamically sized based on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with two sheets.

Sheet1 gets the raw data (which will always have a different number of columns). I rearrange the columns of the raw data as they to may not be in the same order to "normalize" them. Column CE has a formula that returns True or False.

Sheet2 has formulas that extract certain data from the first sheet.

Formulas on Sheet2:

```
Cell A2: IF(Sheet1!CE2,Sheet1!A2,"")
Cell B2: IF(Sheet1!CE2,Sheet1!B2,"")
Cell C2: IF(Sheet1!CE2,Sheet1!C2,"")
etc.
```

If I put those formulas in Sheet2 and copy down, when I rearrange the columns on Sheet1, the Sheet2 formulas are changed accordingly.

So I have a macro to write all the formulas on Row 2 of Sheet2 AFTER the Sheet1 columns are rearranged.

I have a function that finds the last row of Sheet1.

I want to copy the Sheet2 formulas down the same number of rows that are in Sheet1.

```
'All of the formulas are in row1
lastRow = GetLastRow() 'This successfully retrieves a Long with the last row# of Sheet1

'Be sure am on correct sheet
Sheets("Sheet2").Select

'Copy the formulas
Range("A2:O2").Select
Selection.Copy

'Paste the formulas to the range
'THIS BLOWS UP
Sheet2.Range(startCell, ws1.Cells(lastRow, "O")).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic example of how to fill a range with an equation. This will just look at `Column A` on both sheets.

I am using `Sheet1 Column A` to determine the last row. Change this as needed. Update the columns wherever needed and duplicate the `.Formula` statement as many times as needed to get your desired result

---

Notice that you do not need to `.Select` anything to modify it. VBA is indifferent to the active sheet when you properly qualify your objects.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PhilNye()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim LRow As Long
LRow = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ws2.Range("A2:A" & LRow).Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!CE2, Sheet1!A2,"""")" '<-- Duplicate This Statement

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively: put your formulas in sheet2 as desired before rearranging sheet1. Then search and replace changing the = sign to nothing. Rearrange sheet1 while formulas are disabled, then search and replace, changing IF to =IF to restore your formulas